# how make tabs scrolling horizontally with activities?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio, android-activity

how can make tabs scrolling horizontally with activities?
Because online i founded only with fragments...

Same this but with activities..

[image]

Comment: This is called `ViewPager` with `TabLayout` . And you must have to use fragment . Coz , From fragment concept we know it can be dynamically add or remove  in a Activity . But you can't do that with activity .

Comment: It is not possible with the activities..

Answer (score 0):

Nested `Activity`s using `TabHost`s are deprecated. To achieve the above behavior, you have to use `Fragment`s. Use a `TabLayout` and `ViewPager` in your `Activity` and in `PagerAdapter` for `ViewPager`, instantiate the `Fragment`s.

Answer (score 0):

add this code `app:tabMode="scrollable"` to your `tab layout`.